# unwanted line feed between <label/> and <a/>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have markup that puts anchors (for help icons) right after `<label/>` elements.  If the label and icon would fix on one line, everything works how I want.  However, if the label causes the text to wrap (due to length), then the icon creates a line feed and renders itself on a new line.  I want the icon to simply appear 'after' the label on the same line no matter how many lines the label takes.

This is the result of the rendering (in case screen sizes aren't right - note, I don't know why Font Awesome isn't working in the fiddle, but you can still see the issue):

[image]

CSS

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019</label>
      <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
      </a>      
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019 with longer text so that it wraps</label>
      <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
      </a>      
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8x2na97d/

Comment: You are required to post your markup or code here **within your question** and NEVER any third party site! [mcve]

Comment: What?!  I see fiddles linked all the time.

Comment: And if everyone else jumped off a cliff, you would to? There are only a limited number of people who can delete such questions and answers. It takes time for us to get to them. Yours is up for removal. The rules are clear. Post your code here or it will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the anchor tags inside label.

```
<label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019       
  <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
  </a>  
</label>
```

Solution : https://jsfiddle.net/hqx5wjop/1/

It happens because label is displayed as an `inline-block` and anchor tag is displayed as `inline`

You can also solve it by adding the style

```
display: inline;
```

to label tag

Comment: I should have specified that I *didn't* want the a inside the label.  The reason being is because this is part of a core html library we use. It was changed to put the anchor outside the label I *think* because it was doing that (anchor inside the label) for radio buttons too and that was causing problems.  I'll see about adding display: inline for labels (I didn't want to change 'bootstrap' behavior, but the fiddle seems fine).

Answer (score 1):

Set this CSS:

```
label{
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code `label{display:inline;}`

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
label{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019 ffddff</label>
      <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
      </a>      
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019 with longer text so that it wraps</label>
      <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
      </a>      
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This is the absolute opposite of what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you for label and fa icon in same line,

```
   <style>
       .row {
        background: #f8f9fa;
        margin-top: 20px;
       }

 .col {
   border: solid 0px #6c757d;
   padding: 10px;
 }
     </style>

   <body>
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019
             <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
             <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
            </a></label>   
          </div>

         <div class="col">
            <label class="control-label liMedicare" for="iMedicare">I enrolled in Medicare in 2019 with longer text so that it wraps
            <a class="vhiMedicare" style="" role="button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="fal fa-question-circle"></span>
            </a> </label>     
          </div>

         <div class="col">
             3 of 3
          </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
   </body>
```